# I forgot to submit my HSA tax forms last year can I add it this year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa

My 2015 HSA paperwork didn't make it to me until after the tax deadline. My employer switched HSA providers so I have everything on time this year. Can I add the HSA from last year?

Should I assume that not adding the HSA had me pay more taxes than I should have because the contributions should be tax exempt?

Also I noticed the answer for [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/26581/i-forgot-to-deduct-my-hsa-contribution-in-my-2012-tax-return-how-can-i-file-an) might be useful. Is it safe to say if box 12 on the W-2 is filled out, I don't need any special HSA tax forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the other question gives what I would initially respond with, that you probably did have the deduction on the previous tax year. If you are using your employer's HSA provider, they likely withheld the amounts from your paychecks and reported them on your W-2.

If after examining your prior year's taxes, you need to make changes, the proper way to do that is to file a 1040-X. **You should NOT** report contributions that are not supported by the paperwork you received for THIS tax year. The IRS will likely have that automatically flagged in their system and amend your return for you in a couple of years if they find such a mistake, then they will charge you interest and possibly even penalties for the difference.

Comment: turns out it was in box 12W so i actually did submit it. Thanks.